# Mirror a literal array in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, arrays, webstorm, reverse, mirror

I got a literal JavaScript array in WebStorm.

```
//example
var arr = [9,7,5,3,1];
```

I want to mirror that array in editor, the result should be like this.

```
//result
var arr = [1,3,5,7,9];
```

I don't want to sort the array, but mirror its values.

Comment: Open up the console, put your literal into it, run reverse() on it, stringify the result (`JSON.stringify([9,7,5,3,1].reverse())`), paste the final string back into the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use JavaScript `reverse()`.

```js
var arr = [9,7,5,3,1];
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I was wondering is there any plugin or feature in Webstorm to do it right in the editor.

Comment: WebStrom is a JavaScript based IDE. You can write any JavaScipt code in there. Also you can use any third party plugin which supports the same. Though I believe, this is the simplest way to accomplish your task. Using unnecessary function from third party plugin only decrease the performance of the application.